# Text on x-axis ticks for scatterplot with standard-error bars

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, axis-labels, errorbar

I am trying to plot scatterplots which have an error-bar each. See code below:

```
dfs = [0 5 10];
Accuracies = [63.1681  49  56];
SE = [0.0142 0.065 0.04 ]*100;

errorbar(dfs, Accuracies, SE, 'ro');
hold on
plot(dfs,Accuracies,'bo');
title('Accuracies');
hold off;
ylim([40 70])
names = {'Cond1'; 'Cond2'; 'Cond3'};
set(gca,'xtick',[1:3],'xticklabel',names)
```

However, the x-axis labels are not properly aligned. What is the solution for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `xtick`s to `dfs`. Setting them to `[1:3]` keeps only `[1 2 3]` and removes the rest.

```
set(gca, 'xtick', dfs, 'xticklabel', names);
xlim([-1 11]);  %just for better visualisation
```

[image: result]

Comment: Many thanks Sardar:) Another question: Is it possible to make the dots larger? Best regards, Pegah

Comment: You need to change the `'MarkerSize'` property for that while using `errorbar` and `plot`.